# Can I change the bot names in CS:Source?

Tags: counter-strike-source

I've had CS:S for a week and I'm already getting tired of the terrible bland bot names. Is there a file tucked away somewhere that allows me to put in custom names?

Comment: Semi-answering my own question, you need to have a file called "botprofile.db" in your main cstrike directory. This is present on servers by default, but if you're running your own server based on the Steam client you won't have it. I found a modified copy here: http://filebase.bots-united.com/uploads/AltBotProfile.db -- it works ok, but if someone can post an original, vanilla botprofile.db I'll give you the answer points...

Comment: I'm putting a bounty on this question which will go to the first person who can give me a default **botprofile.db** ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A according to [source](http://forums.eventscripts.com/viewtopic.php?t=28880), this is the default template.  However, since all values that aren't changed already use default, it would seem that to do what you want you don't actually need to know what default is:

```
//
// This database defines bot "personalities". 
// Feel free to edit it and define your own bots.
//


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
// All profiles begin with this data and overwrite their own
//
Default
   Skill = 50
   Aggression = 50
   ReactionTime = 0.3
   AttackDelay = 0
   Teamwork = 75
   WeaponPreference = none
   Cost = 0
   Difficulty = NORMAL
   VoicePitch = 100
   Skin = 0
End

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//
// These templates inherit from Default and override with their values
// The name of the template defines a type that is used by individual bot profiles
//

// weapon preference templates
Template Rifle
   WeaponPreference = m4a1
   WeaponPreference = ak47
   WeaponPreference = famas
   WeaponPreference = galil
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End

Template RifleT
   WeaponPreference = ak47
   WeaponPreference = m4a1
   WeaponPreference = galil
   WeaponPreference = famas
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End

Template Punch
   WeaponPreference = aug
   WeaponPreference = sg552
   WeaponPreference = famas
   WeaponPreference = galil
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End

Template PunchT
   WeaponPreference = aug
   WeaponPreference = sg552
   WeaponPreference = famas
   WeaponPreference = galil
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End

Template Sniper
   WeaponPreference = awp
   WeaponPreference = sg550
   WeaponPreference = g3sg1
   WeaponPreference = scout
   WeaponPreference = famas
   WeaponPreference = galil
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End

Template Power
   WeaponPreference = m249
   WeaponPreference = xm1014
   WeaponPreference = m3
   WeaponPreference = famas
   WeaponPreference = galil
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End

Template Shotgun
   WeaponPreference = xm1014
   WeaponPreference = m3
   WeaponPreference = famas
   WeaponPreference = galil
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End

Template Shield
//   WeaponPreference = shield
   WeaponPreference = m4a1         // in case shield is disallowed
   WeaponPreference = ak47
   WeaponPreference = famas
   WeaponPreference = galil
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End

Template Spray
   WeaponPreference = p90
   WeaponPreference = tmp
   WeaponPreference = mac10
   WeaponPreference = mp5
End


// skill templates
Template Elite
   Skill = 100
   Aggression = 100
   ReactionTime = 0.2
   Cost = 4
   Difficulty = EXPERT
   VoicePitch = 85
End

Template Expert
   Skill = 90
   Aggression = 90
   ReactionTime = 0.2
   Cost = 4
   Difficulty = EXPERT
   VoicePitch = 88
End

Template VeryHard
   Skill = 80
   Aggression = 80
   ReactionTime = 0.25
   Cost = 3
   Difficulty = HARD
   VoicePitch = 92
End

Template Hard
   Skill = 75
   Aggression = 75
   ReactionTime = 0.25
   Cost = 3
   Difficulty = HARD
   VoicePitch = 94
End

Template Tough
   Skill = 60
   Aggression = 60
   ReactionTime = 0.3
   AttackDelay = 0.35
   Cost = 2
   Difficulty = NORMAL+HARD
   VoicePitch = 96
End

Template Normal
   Skill = 50
   Aggression = 50
   ReactionTime = 0.4
   AttackDelay = 0.7
   Cost = 2
   Difficulty = NORMAL
End

Template Fair
   Skill = 25
   Aggression = 30
   ReactionTime = 0.4
   AttackDelay = 1.0
   Cost = 1
   Difficulty = EASY+NORMAL
   VoicePitch = 105
End

Template Easy
   Skill = 0
   Aggression = 20
   ReactionTime = 0.5
   AttackDelay = 1.5
   Cost = 1
   Difficulty = EASY
   VoicePitch = 110
End

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//
// These are the individual bot profiles, which inherit first from 
// Default and then the specified Template(s), in order
//

Elite+Rifle Cliffe
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Elite+Spray Minh
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 105
End

Elite+Shotgun Crusher
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 84
End

Elite+Punch Pheonix
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Elite+Power Rock
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 80
End

Elite+PunchT Shark
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 90
End

Elite+Rifle Wolf
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Elite+RifleT Gunner
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 96
End

Elite+Sniper Zed
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 105
End

Elite+RifleT Steel
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 84
End

Elite+PunchT Stone
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 86
End


//----------------------------------------

Expert+RifleT Arnold
   VoicePitch = 85
End

Expert+Rifle Brett
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Expert+Punch Kurt
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Expert+Sniper Kyle
   Cost = 5
   VoicePitch = 115
End

Expert+Shotgun Moe
   VoicePitch = 87
End

Expert+Rifle Quade
   VoicePitch = 91
End

Expert+Rifle Quintin
   VoicePitch = 101
End

Expert Ringo
   VoicePitch = 112
End

Expert+PunchT Rip
   VoicePitch = 99
End

Expert+Rifle Zach
   VoicePitch = 100
End

//----------------------------------------

VeryHard+Power Cory
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 110
End

VeryHard+Sniper Quinn
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 93
End

VeryHard+Rifle Seth
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 100
End

VeryHard+RifleT Vinny
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 86
End


//----------------------------------------

Hard+Rifle Chad
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Hard+RifleT Chet
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 90
End

Hard+Spray Gabe
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 102
End

Hard+Shotgun Hank
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Hard+RifleT Ivan
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 96
End

Hard+Punch Jim
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 103
End

Hard+PunchT Joe
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 105
End

Hard+Rifle John
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 97
End

Hard+Rifle Tony
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 84
End

Hard+PunchT Tyler
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 90
End

Hard+Rifle Victor
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Hard+Sniper Vladimir
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Hard+Spray Zane
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 103
End

Hard+Rifle Zim
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 110
End

//----------------------------------------

Tough+Sniper Adrian
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 120
End

Tough+Rifle Brad
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Tough+Rifle Connor
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 104
End

Tough+RifleT Dave
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Tough Dan
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Tough+Rifle Derek
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 102
End

Tough+Shotgun Don
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Tough+Rifle Eric
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Tough+RifleT Erik
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Tough+Rifle Finn
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 112
End

Tough Jeff
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 90
End

Tough+Rifle Kevin
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 115
End

Tough+RifleT Reed
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 107
End

Tough+Rifle Rick
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 102
End

Tough Ted
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Tough+Rifle Troy
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Tough+RifleT Wade
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Tough+Rifle Wayne
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 86
End

Tough+RifleT Xander
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Tough+Rifle Xavier
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 95
End

//----------------------------------------

Normal+Rifle Adam
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 105
End

Normal+PunchT Andy
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 90
End

Normal Chris
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Normal Colin
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 107
End

Normal+Shield Dennis
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 104
End

Normal Doug
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Normal Gary
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Normal Grant
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 112
End

Normal Greg
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 111
End

Normal+Sniper Ian
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 115
End

Normal Jerry
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 112
End

Normal Jon
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 96
End

Normal Keith
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Normal Mark
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Normal Matt
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Normal+RifleT Mike
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Normal Nate
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 99
End

Normal Paul
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Normal Scott
   Skin = 1
   VoicePitch = 105
End

Normal Steve
   Skin = 2
   VoicePitch = 115
End

Normal Tom
   Skin = 3
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Normal Yahn
   Skin = 4
   VoicePitch = 92
End

//----------------------------------------

Fair Alfred
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Fair Bill
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Fair Brandon
   VoicePitch = 99
End

Fair+Spray Calvin
   VoicePitch = 120
End

Fair Dean
   VoicePitch = 111
End

Fair Dustin
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Fair Ethan
   VoicePitch = 112
End

Fair Harold
   VoicePitch = 90
End

Fair Henry
   VoicePitch = 120
End

Fair Irving
   VoicePitch = 118
End

Fair Jason
   VoicePitch = 116
End

Fair Josh
   VoicePitch = 114
End

Fair Martin
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Fair Nick
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Fair Norm
   VoicePitch = 92
End

Fair Orin
   VoicePitch = 113
End

Fair Pat
   VoicePitch = 114
End

Fair Perry
   VoicePitch = 115
End

Fair Ron
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Fair Shawn
   VoicePitch = 102
End

Fair Tim
   VoicePitch = 98
End

Fair Will
   VoicePitch = 96
End

Fair Wyatt
   VoicePitch = 94
End

//----------------------------------------

Easy Albert
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Easy Allen
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Easy Bert
   VoicePitch = 120
End

Easy Bob
   VoicePitch = 99
End

Easy Cecil
   VoicePitch = 120
End

Easy Clarence
   VoicePitch = 125
End

Easy Elliot
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Easy Elmer
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Easy Ernie
   VoicePitch = 112
End

Easy Eugene
   VoicePitch = 121
End

Easy Fergus
   VoicePitch = 99
End

Easy Ferris
   VoicePitch = 119
End

Easy Frank
   VoicePitch = 118
End

Easy Frasier
   VoicePitch = 117
End

Easy Fred
   VoicePitch = 116
End

Easy George
   VoicePitch = 115
End

Easy Graham
   VoicePitch = 114
End

Easy Harvey
   VoicePitch = 112
End

Easy Irwin
   VoicePitch = 111
End

Easy Lester
   VoicePitch = 110
End

Easy Marvin
   VoicePitch = 109
End

Easy Neil
   VoicePitch = 108
End

Easy Niles
   VoicePitch = 122
End

Easy Oliver
   VoicePitch = 120
End

Easy Opie
   VoicePitch = 125
End

Easy Toby
   VoicePitch = 92
End

Easy Ulric
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Easy Ulysses
   VoicePitch = 102
End

Easy Uri
   VoicePitch = 104
End

Easy Waldo
   VoicePitch = 108
End

Easy Wally
   VoicePitch = 95
End

Easy Walt
   VoicePitch = 100
End

Easy Wesley
   VoicePitch = 120
End

Easy Yanni
   VoicePitch = 112
End

Easy Yogi
   VoicePitch = 99
End

Easy Yuri
   VoicePitch = 110
End
```

Comment: I needed the entire template because you can't change names without including all the other stuff like `Expert+Shotgun` and I didn't want to guess about those arrangements. Thank you.

Comment: @Shaderach glad I could help.  Even I am not above working for an extra 100 rep reward

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't realize selecting and answer and awarding the bounty are two separate actions. I've never used the bounty feature before. :)

Comment: @Shader I actually made that mistake before and it resulted in the bounty not being assigned... :(